# I'm looking for the meaning of 'metrological center' in an engineering context

Tags: word-meaning, terminology

What does "metrological center" in this sentence mean?

> The inverse cubic fit allows to determine the center of the dechirper with respect to the electron beam, which might differ from the metrological center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

metrology means the study of measures (and weights) so the *metrological center* would be the actual measured center, as opposed to the "center of the dechirper" (as for what that part means - you're on your own ;) )

Comment: Ah, this makes sense. The metrological center would therefore be the center of the device with respect to itself, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, I'd say so!